# Adding field to users database in asp.net webforms application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework-6

I am new to VS2015 and have it up an running.  My preference is to run in VB and I have a sample asp.net web ap open.  With new entity framework I am trying to add a field "PrincipalID" to the aspnetusers database.  I have migrations enabled and added the field to the register.aspx code file.  I added the migration and ran the updated-database without errors, but the new field does not show up in the database.  Anybody know why?

Code segment in register.aspx file:

```
Partial Public Class Register
Inherits Page
Protected Sub CreateUser_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim userName As String = Email.Text
    Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
    Dim signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get(Of ApplicationSignInManager)()
    Dim user = New ApplicationUser() With {.UserName = userName, .Email = userName, .PrincipalID = "test"}
    Dim result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text)
    If result.Succeeded Then
        ' For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
        ' Dim code = manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id)
        ' Dim callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, user.Id, Request)
        ' manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=""" & callbackUrl & """>here</a>.")

        signInManager.SignIn(user, isPersistent := False, rememberBrowser := False)
        IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"), Response)
    Else
        ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault()
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Add a Try Catch and see if there is an error thrown. Do you have write permissions to the DB as the entity running this code?

Comment: Did you add the property PrincipalID to the ApplicationUser class? Then add the migration and update the database

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh the connection , On services or Data Source Tab , Refresh your connection string and all your new fields will load up .

Comment: Thank you.  I have refreshed the connection and that is not it. As far as write permission goes, the DB was created by the application and I can add users to the DB and have also gotten roles to work for users, so it seems to me that writing to the DB is working. See the code, I believe that PrinciplID is added to the Application User class.  It was added automatically (I believe) when I right-clicked the new entry of PrincipalID and selected 'create field'.  I changed it from 'Friend' to "public" to see if that had any affect.  If I inserted a 'try-catch', where would that go?

Comment: 'Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Security.Claims
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework

' You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your User class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
Public Class ApplicationUser
    Inherits IdentityUser

    Public PrincipalID As String


    Public Function GenerateUserIdentity(manager As